# installation of drivers for easypen i405x for ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, tablet, graphics-tablet

Have you installed easypen i405x ,if yes, can you please put the detailed steps you followed for installing the tablet ? Like where did you find the drivers .In product specification it says that i405x works on Windows only ? Please answer

Comment: This question is also related.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/547041/pen-tablet-mousepen-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

The [EasyPen i405x is supported in Ubuntu as of Kernel 3.4](https://digimend.github.io/tablets/KYE_EasyPen_i405X/) which is available in Ubuntu 14.04. If it is not working, you can obtain the driver directly from the [DIGImend project](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers). Building and installation instructions are available there.

You will need to obtain the appropriate headers for your kernel with the command `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Then, after downloading the source code package from the [DIGImend project](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers), you can build and install it with

`make && sudo make install`

Please refer directly to [DIGImend documentation](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/blob/master/README.md) in case they ever change.